# Issue with creating and renaming a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line

In Python I wrote a little script, using an astronomy command line tool, called tempo2, which creates a file called 'polyco_new.dat'. I want to rename the newly created file, by using the filepath.

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np

with open('paths.txt', 'r') as paths_list:
    for file_path in paths_list:
        data = np.loadtxt(file_path.strip())
        filename = file_path[-26:-5]

        # creates the 'polyco_new.dat'-file
        os.system("tempo2 -tempo1 -polyco  \"%f %f 120 15 12 @ 0\" -f  ephemerides.par" %(t0, te))  

        # renames the file
        os.rename('polyco_new.dat', 'polycox_'+filename+'.dat')
```

However, I get the error that the 'polyco_new.dat' does not exist (no such file or directory), even though I know it is created by the tempo2 tool.

How can I make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably lies to the difference between the directory used by default by `tempo2` to create files and the current working directory from where your Python script is launched. To fix it, do:

```
# creates the 'polyco_new.dat'-file
os.system("tempo2 -tempo1 -polyco  \"%f %f 120 15 12 @ 0\" -f  ephemerides.par" %(t0, te))  

# assuming the file was created in C:\some\directory
os.chdir(r'C:\some\directory')
os.rename('polyco_new.dat', 'polycox_{}.dat'.format(filename))
```

Comment: The polyco_new.dat-file is created in the same directory, though. If I just run the part with tempo2, I see the file showing up in this directory. But if I add the renaming command, only then I get the error.

Comment: I tried it with adding the os.chdir(r'theabsolutepath'), but I still get the same error.

Comment: @user90465 You are the only one that can debug this. I do not know what `tempo2` does and how and why and when. But underneath the `os.chdir` you can try doing `os.listdir()` to see the contents of the current folder. The file that you are creating should be in there. If not; which seems to be the case, you are doing something wrong.